# Dual boot :Windows 7 partition deleted after Kubuntu 14.04 install...Weird!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu, data-recovery

I've bought two new SSD's in order to install Kubuntu on one and Win 7 on the other one. Before I had Linux Mint and Win7 together one just one SSD.
So first I installed win7 as recommended, and then used the guided installer of Kubuntu to install Kubuntu. I selected the second SSD, chose the option "use entire disk and install", but to my surprise after rebooting and selecting win7 boot loader from grub2, I got a prompt that my windows installation is damaged, and I need to run the repair option from the installation disk. So I booted into Kubuntu again, fired up kparted and saw that indeed my windows partition got deleted, except the recovery partition.

I don't understand what happened. I am not new to this topic, and this was not my first time installing Ubuntu alongside windows. I have never ever had that problem.
What can I do to make sure this won't happen again, so I won't waste another 2 hours of my life?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

There is another option in the installer, the last one, called **Something else**. Select this option and manually format/mount any new or already existing partition (including NTFS partitions). This variant will do nothing automatically, only what you want.